# I use pyserial module, but can only read, can't send data and blocked

Tags: python, pyserial

I use pyserial module, but can only read, can't send data, what's the matter? I use Python 3.7.
I use two serial port tools to connect, one is com9, the other is com10. No matter I send with com9 or com10, the other com port can receive data, but it can't send successfully. What's more, I found another problem that serialport.write function was blocked after executing twice. What's the matter?

```
import serial

comport = "com10"
baudrate = 9600
serialport = serial.Serial(comport, int(baudrate), timeout=1, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, rtscts=1)

if serialport.isOpen():
     print("open success")
else:
     print("open failed")

while 1:
     ret = serialport.readline()
     if ret != 0:
     sendData = "hello\r\n"
     ret = serialport.write(sendData.encode('utf-8'))
     print(ret)
```

Comment: use `serialport.write(bytes(sendData, encoding= 'utf-8'))`

Comment: @Jared still not.

Comment: How, exactly, are the two serial ports physically connected to each other?  Enabling hardware flow control is not appropriate if the cable doesn't connect the flow control lines.

Comment: @jasonharper txd1 connect rxd2，rxd1 connect txd2 ，gnd1 connect gnd2.

Comment: Ok, then you absolutely do not have the capability to use hardware flow control over this connection.

Comment: @jasonharper good,  after I set rtscts is 0, I can write successfully! but why? Could you give me a simple explanation, please.